# HTML5 doesn't load a hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to make a toggle-able chart and everything works fine if it starts off with the chart is visible. However, if I use `display: none` and then toggle, the chart doesn't show the actual candlesticks bars and I can't figure out why.

Supposed to be:

[image: Supposed to be]

Here is my code:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/YZYjBq)

```js
var chart = new cryptowatch.Embed('bitfinex', 'btcusd', {
  timePeriod: '1d',
  width: 650,
  customColorScheme: {
    bg: "000000",
    text: "b2b2b2",
    textStrong: "e5e5e5",
    textWeak: "7f7f7f",
    short: "FD4600",
    shortFill: "FF672C",
    long: "6290FF",
    longFill: "002782",
    cta: "363D52",
    ctaHighlight: "414A67",
    alert: "FFD506",
  }
});
chart.mount('#chart-container');

$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#chart-container').toggle(200);
});
```

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#chart-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: none;
}

#btn {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 200px;
  border: black 2px solid;
  padding: 2px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="btn">click</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.cryptowat.ch/assets/scripts/embed.bundle.js"></script>
```

Please comment out `display: none`, you will see what I mean.

Comment: Please use the `<>` snippet editor here instead

Comment: @mplungjan can you see than candlesticks or just the empty black frame?

Comment: Ah, I see the empty frame

Comment: Could be a browser issue or cache .. because it works fine in google chorme

Comment: @M.KHossain - I get the same problem in Chrome.

Comment: I think by by using display none, I accidentally hide the content of the graph and then only toggle the frame?

Comment: @nnnnnn can you give me a screenshot please, Cause i can not find that problem. another thing when i change that display property as block it takes 1 or 2 seconds to lode the graph, but the black part comes imminently. so please let me know if this is the problem..

Comment: @M.KHossain - I'm not the OP, I'm not going to go making screenshots. But with `display:none` the graph doesn't work: clicking the button shows an *empty* graph. Without `display:none` the graph appears immediately, but it does work.

Comment: @nnnnnn I included a screenshot of how it should looks like after toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `wrapper` to the `chart-container` and then toggle i.e. its height it will work.

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqpaRw)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="chart-container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container.show {
  height: 400px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('#container').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you boss. Do you know what caused it?

Comment: @Icoined Using `display: none` can give issues where some drawings won't draw because the fact that the element is just that, not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use "getElementById()" function of javascript instead of using "display: none" property of css.

For Example:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Div changed!";
```

Hopefully this will works fine.
Thank you :)

Comment: I'm struggling to see the connection between this answer and the question. Did you look at what was happening in the OP's demo? The content of the DIV is getting set by a charting library.

Comment: yes bro.
First of all read your question properly.
please ask question in proper way bro. so that you can get proper ans.